# GMap.NET shows no map

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I'm trying to use the [GMap.NET.WindowsForms](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=20235) control in my Windows forms application but I cannot make it show me any map.

Here is what I did:

I added the control to my Visual Studio's 2010 toolbox by clicking 'Choose Items...' from the toolbox's context menu and browsing for the GMap.NET.WindowsForms.dll included in the downloaded zip archive. I also added references to GMap.NET.Core.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll in my solution.

Then I put the GMapControl that appeared in the toolbox on the main form of my application and set the map type to GoogleMap. When I run my application, however, the control shows either a blue screen with a piece of text saying "We are sorry, but we don't have imagery at this zoom level for this region" or a bright screen with completely no data (when I change zoom level).

Here is my code:

```
  GMapMain.MapType = MapType.GoogleMap;
  GMapMain.MaxZoom = 100;
  GMapMain.MinZoom = 0;
  GMapMain.Zoom = 50;
  GMapMain.CurrentPosition = new PointLatLng(54.6961334816182, 25.2985095977783);

  GMapMain.ReloadMap();
```

Please help. I have no idea what to do and I cannot find any information in the Internet that could help me solve the problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting the instance mode to server only

GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly

Answer (score 7):

You could use following statements before using gmap Control.

```
GMapProvider.WebProxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
GMapProvider.WebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: I have developed an application with included GMap.net. The application has worked without problem in our environment. In the customer environment, I had the error-message exception "the operation has timed out". To add this code (overtake proxy settings) has resolved the problem. Thanks for your posting Sudhakar!

Comment: if i could i would vote this answer ten times. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your zoom level looks too high.
The zoom should be between 1 and 17.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help :(. I still get bright screen with no map at all.

Comment: No, I didn't. Could you please tell me what it is and how to do it?

Comment: OK, I managed to solve the problem. I downloaded the source of a demo application provided by the author of that control and copied all necessary code that initializes the map from there. The thing was that I used ServerAndCache access mode and when I changed it to Server access mode, the control displayed map correctly. I'm not sure why. I might have not set some important properties of the control, I don't know which, however. Thanks for your suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.7.0 of GMap.NET the satellite view is not working, you should download the lastest version from here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/GMap.NET.Presentation/

with that you can use the satellite view.

If you can see the satellite view in your environmet it's because you have the map in the cache but you will can not see some places. With the new version, you will download the map from the server and you will see it well.