# GMap.NET c# integration

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmap.net

I would like to integrate GMap.NET in a c# application but when i download the code from http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/ a get a Demo app and some .dlls and some .xmls . I was sort of expecting some c# classes. Has anyone encountered this?

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: Add a reference to the DLL's and you'll be set. Damn good library that is!

Comment: i've added the references but don't know what to call. Any documentation available?

Answer (score 2):

figured it out! this helped: [GMap.NET shows no map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996101/gmap-net-shows-no-map)