# Error 403 - Forbidden on Loading Open Street Map to Win Form with GMap.Net and C#

Tags: openstreetmap, gmap.net

Trying to load OSM on windows Form using C# and GMap.Net I am getting this error

> Exception:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        gMapControl1.CanDragMap = true;
        gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        gMapControl1.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(54.6961334816182, 25.2985095977783);
        gMapControl1.MinZoom = 0;
        gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 24;
        gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;
        gMapControl1.AutoScroll = true;


    }
```

Can you please let me know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the complete HTTP request and response, e.g. using wireshark? Which OSM tile server are you using? Does your program respect the [tile usage policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/), for example does it send a valid referrer?

Comment: To complement scai's comment, usually tile servers (and their stylesheets) don't go above 18-20 zoom level. It should not result in HTTP 403 statuses, but beware of this.

Comment: @scai, thanks for reply where can I check the Tile server? I mean as I said I am using GMap.Net so how can I check the request or tile usage policy?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I've never used this framework.

Comment: @Behseini Did you ever solve this? I assume it's some kind of policy issue with OSM (GMap.NET seems to have a lot of those kind of issues).

Comment: This is also an error that occurred suddenly, after years of using the service. Switching to BingProvider fixes the problem, but question is for how long. Is there a way to contat openstreetmap.org and ask them if they blocked?

Answer (score 2):

don't forget to set the instance mode to server/cache and set it to the instance of the open street map provider instead of 'GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap'

```
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache; 
gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.OpenStreetMapProvider.Instance;
```

It could also be your web proxy settings, see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609539/2368681

Answer (score 1):

"Hi,

All libraries that send a fake user-agent and other faked headers to make the requests appear as if they are coming from web browsers are being blocked. Fix the headers and set a real User-Agent to identify your app and the requests will work again.

Please review our usage policy:
https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/ "

This is verbatim reply from OSM.

https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/pull/45 is being used to track this issue. And hopefully a fix will be merged in a a day or two.

Answer (score 1):

I changed Map Provider from "OpenStreetMapProvider" to "GoogleMapProvider" and the error disappeared.

GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
mapView.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;